# On Lee's proof of conservative covector field being equivalent to exactness

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am confused with a statement from the following proof on John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Namely, the last sentence in the last second paragraph states that since the component functions of $\omega$ are smooth and equal to the partial derivatives of $f$ in coordinates, this also shows that $f$ is smooth.

My concerns here is the following:
In the proof that he shows $\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial x^j} (q_0) = \omega_j(q_0)$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ is a tangent vector, meaning it is a derivation at $q_0$, so for this $\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial x^j} (q_0)$ to make sense, don't we need $\tilde f$ to be smooth in the first place? I feel like this is a bit circular reasoning. In the book page 60, the partial derivative $\partial/\partial x^i|_p$ is defined as the derivation that takes the $i$th partial derivative of (the coordinate representation of) $f$ at (the coordinate representation of) $p$. Hence, it seems to me that for $\frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial x^j} (q_0)$ to make sense $\tilde f$ being smooth should be established first.

[image]

[image]

[image]